# CSS keyframes doesn't work with Firefox (23.0.1)

Tags: firefox, css-transitions, parallax, css-animations

I've got a problem with @keyframes. It works perfectly fine with Chrome and Opera but some elements (big.h class or p) not animating with Firefox (newest version 23.0.1). What is interesting is that every prefix is written the same way (-webkit-, -o- or simply @keyframes) Image animates correctly. It is modified Parallax Content Slider. I'll be very grateful for help.

HTML code:

```
<div id="ja-topsl" class="clearfix">
        <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
            <div class="da-slide">
                <span class="big_h">Skrypt portalu informacyjnego</span>
                <p>Uniwersalny skrypt zawierający wszystkie niezbędne elementy do prowadzenia serwisu informacyjnego. Rozbudowane narzędzia redakcyjne, tematyczne forum, ogłoszenia, dział TV. Modyfikacja i wprowadzanie nowych treści jest proste i intuicyjne.</p>
                <a href="portal-informacyjny-skrypt.html" class="da-link">Zobacz demo skryptu</a>
                <a href="serwisy-tematyczne-skrypty.html" class="da-link1"><strong>lub sprawdź inne skrypty tej kategorii</strong></a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="templates/interactiv/slider/images/produkt.png" alt="Skrypt portalu informacyjnego" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="da-slide">
                <span class="big_h">Projektowanie responsywne</span>
                <p>Zdecydowana większość projektów sklepów i stron WWW to layouty responsywne. Oznacza to, że projekty te dostosowane są do optymalnego wyświetlania na urządzeniach typu desktop, tablet oraz na ekranach telefonów komórkowych.</p>
                <a href="projekty_responsywne.html" class="da-link">Przeglądaj projekty</a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="templates/interactiv/slider/images/produkt2.png" alt="Projektowanie responsywne" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="da-slide">
                <span class="big_h">Skrypt serwisu finansowego</span>
                <p>Intuicyjny portalowy wygląd, forum, działy tematyczne, informacje z banków, kursy oraz wykresy giełdowe. Możliwość sprzedaży produktów finansowych bezpośrednio w serwisie oraz zarabiania na reklamie kontekstowej i programach partnerskich.</p>
                <a href="portal-finansowy-skrypt.html" class="da-link">Zobacz demo skryptu</a>
                <a href="serwisy-tematyczne-skrypty.html" class="da-link1"><strong>lub sprawdź inne skrypty tej kategorii</strong></a>
                <div class="da-img"><img src="templates/interactiv/slider/images/produkt3.png" alt="image01" /></div>
            </div>
            <nav class="da-arrows">
                <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.da-slider{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    height: 303px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent url(../images/tlo_slidera.png) repeat 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    -o-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.da-slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.da-slide-current{
    z-index: 1000;
}
.da-slider-fb .da-slide{
    left: 100%;
}
.da-slider-fb  .da-slide.da-slide-current{
    left: 0px;
}
.da-slide .big_h,
.da-slide p,
.da-slide .da-link,
.da-slide .da-link1,
.da-slide .da-img{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 110%;
}
.da-slider-fb .da-slide .big_h,
.da-slider-fb .da-slide p,
.da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-link,
.da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-link1 {
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-img{
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slide .big_h{
    color: #373737;
    width: 50%;
    top: 25px;
    left: 20px !important;
    z-index: 10;
}

.da-slide p{
    width: 430px;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 75px;
    color: #666666;
    left: 37px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 400 14px/14px "open sans";
    line-height: 25px;
}

.da-slide .da-img{
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 256px;
    line-height: 320px;
    left: 110%; /*60%*/
}
.da-slide .da-link{
    top: 200px; /*depends on p height*/
    left: 125px !important;
   border: 1px solid #c52626;
   background: #b42e2e;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d23434), to(#b42e2e));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d23434, #b42e2e);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d23434, #b42e2e);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d23434, #b42e2e);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d23434, #b42e2e);
   padding: 8px 35px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: #760000 0 4px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: #760000 0 4px 0;
   box-shadow: #760000 0 4px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.da-slide .da-link:hover{
   top: 200px; /*depends on p height*/
   left: 125px !important;
   border: 1px solid #d73333;
   background: #d73333;
   color: #ffffff;
}

.da-slide .da-link1{
    top: 250px; /*depends on p height*/
    left: 125px !important;
    width: 280px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    font: 400 14px/14px "open sans";
}

.da-slide .da-link1:hover{
    top: 250px; /*depends on p height*/
    left: 125px !important;
    width: 280px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #000000;
}

.da-dots{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
    left: 430px;
    z-index: 2000;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.da-dots span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -pie-border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(/templates/interactiv/pie/PIE.htc);
    background: #ce2c2c;
    margin: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.da-dots span.da-dots-current:after{
    content: '';
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -pie-border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(/templates/interactiv/pie/PIE.htc);
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,237,237,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );

    }
.da-arrows{
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.da-arrows span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -pie-border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(/templates/interactiv/pie/PIE.htc);
    background: #ce2c2c;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2000;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.da-slider:hover .da-arrows span{
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-arrows span:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: transparent url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.da-arrows span:hover:after{
}
.da-arrows span:active:after{
}
.da-arrows span.da-arrows-next:after{
    background-position: top right;
}
.da-arrows span.da-arrows-prev{
    left: 15px;
}
.da-arrows span.da-arrows-next{
    right: 15px;
}

.da-slide-current .big_h,
.da-slide-current p,
.da-slide-current .da-link,
.da-slide-current .da-link1{
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slide-current .da-img{
    left: 51%;
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Animation classes and animations */

/* Slide in from the right*/
.da-slide-fromright .big_h{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
}
.da-slide-fromright p{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
}
.da-slide-fromright .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
}

.da-slide-fromright .da-link1{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
}

.da-slide-fromright .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-0-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}
/* Slide in from the left*/
.da-slide-fromleft .big_h{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft p{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft .da-link1{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 20px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 37px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 125px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 51%; opacity: 1; }
}
/* Slide out to the right */
.da-slide-toright .big_h{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
.da-slide-toright p{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
}
.da-slide-toright .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toright .da-link1{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toright .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
/* Slide out to the left*/
.da-slide-toleft .big_h{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toLeftAnim1 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toleft p{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.4s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.4s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.4s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.4s ease-in 0.3s both;
    animation: toLeftAnim2 0.4s ease-in 0.3s both;
}
.da-slide-toleft .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toleft .da-link1{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toleft .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 20px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 37px;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 125px;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 125px; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 51%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please link to an actual page or jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Sure, http://bit.ly/1goj7JA. If you have some more questions, let me know.

Comment: OK, and what do I do on that page to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Slider left and right buttons appear when mouseover. It is left/right animation, working fine on Chrome or Opera but some elements (big_h or p) not animating on Firefox. File for CSS is ../slider/css/style.css.

Comment: Hmm.  I see the buttons fade in/out on mouseover/out, but no left/right movement, in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.

Comment: You can't click on those right/left buttons? Weird, I've tested it on FF, Chrome, Opera, IE and few OS's or few different computers.

Comment: Aha, _clicking_ the buttons is the key.  Now I see the different behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `.da-slide .big_h` and `.da-slide p` rules have `!important` values for the `left` property.  The CSS Animations spec drafts used to say that animations override !important, but that got changed late last year.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-animations-20130219/#animations end of first paragraph.  Sounds like Firefox has updated to follow the spec, while Chrome and Opera haven't yet.